# Why an JS object with a property [name] becomes an object with a 'result' property when console logged?

Tags: javascript

I have defined a JS object like below:

`var obj = {
    [name]: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}`

But when I console log it, the printed content became something like below:
{result: "TESTING 201909061509"}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you must using

```
var name = "result"; is present or name is getting assigned this value "result"
```

That's why you are getting result like {result: "TESTING 201909061509"}

To fix the issue try below code

```
var obj = {
name: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}
```

Note: When we define object in JS we define using key and value

```
var obj = {
key1: value1,
key2: value2
};
```

Or Using dot notation

```
obj.key3 = "value3";
```

When we try the way you have tried

Like this

```
 var obj = {
    [name]: 'TESTING 201909061509'
    }
```

Javascript will get the value of [name] and than object will be made if your name is variable which is not defined result will be

```
{"": "TESTING 201909061509"}
```

If it has some value the value will become key like in your case

name has value "result"

> hence result is  {result: "TESTING 201909061509"}

Comment: Hi Vicky, Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation on the issue!

Comment: Cheers @Wayne, happy that it was useful

Answer (score 1):

It's because the value of your variable **name** is actually the string "result".

This way of accessing object's properties is called [Square Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) and it's mostly used when you want your object's attribute to be a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol) (a primitive value) instead of a valid JavaScript [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/identifier).

You can even make it the result of an expression:

```
var obj = { [3+5]: "some value" };
```

Which will result in:

```
{ 8: "some value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the name in square brackets, it is treated like a variable.
If name has a value of "result". Your object looks like

{result: "TESTING 201909061509"}

If you want name in object key it should be

```
var obj = {
    name: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, the rational is correct!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the keys can be define with or without quotation marks, if you prefer to use square brackets in your key you can put the key name inside quotation marks like the below method

```
var obj = {
    ['name']: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}
```

Or

```
var name = 'name';
var obj = {
   [name]: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}
```

Normally we can use like below

```
var obj = {
    name: 'TESTING 201909061509'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to Maiko Morales Roman's answer, if the expression inside the bracket is a Object type, the properties you defined would become [Object Object]. In other words, the Object will transform into String first.

```
const keyA = {a: 1};
const keyB = {b: 2};

const myObject = {
  [keyA]: 'valueA',
  [keyB]: 'valueB'
};

myObject // Object {[object Object]: "valueB"}
```

If you want to set attribute use the variable and its value, you could write your code like this:

```
let birth = '2000/01/01';

const Person = {
  // birth: birth
  birth

};
```